# Зациклить анимацию в CSS (SCSS)

Tags: scss

моих познаний хватило только чтоб сделать (найти и переделать под себя) стиль кнопки, но вот как довести до ума не представляю. Сейчас анимация срабатывает при наведение на кнопку, а нужно чтоб она была зацикленной, точнее повторялась через определений интервал. Такое возможно?

```css
@-webkit-keyframes sheen {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: skewY(-15deg) translateX(0);
            transform: skewY(-15deg) translateX(0);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: skewY(-15deg) translateX(12.5em);
            transform: skewY(-15deg) translateX(12.5em);
  }
}
@keyframes sheen {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: skewY(-15deg) translateX(0);
            transform: skewY(-15deg) translateX(0);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: skewY(-15deg) translateX(12.5em);
            transform: skewY(-15deg) translateX(12.5em);
  }
}
.wrapper {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
          transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.button {
  padding: 0.75em 2em;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #2194e0;
  border: 2px solid #2194e0;
  font-size: 24px;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 0.3em;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.button:before {
  content: "";
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  height: 100%;
  width: 1em;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: -4.5em;
  -webkit-transform: skewX(-15deg) translateX(0);
          transform: skewX(-15deg) translateX(0);
  transition: none;
}
.button:hover {
  background-color: #2194e0;
  color: #fff;
  border-bottom: 4px solid #1977b5;
}
.button:hover:before {
  -webkit-transform: skewX(-15deg) translateX(13.5em);
          transform: skewX(-15deg) translateX(13.5em);
  transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <a href="#" class="button">Shiney!</a>
</div>
```

**Нашел решение задачи. 
Вот такое решение, может кому-то  пригодится:**

```css
body {background: #ffbfbe;}
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  outline: none;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px 30px;
  margin: 10px 20px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 2px solid #fe6637;
  background: #fe6637;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 8px;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif; 
  transition: .2s ease-in-out;
}
a:before {
  content: "";
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(255,255,255,.03), rgba(255,255,255,.5));
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  top: -8px;
  transform: skewX(-45deg);
  animation: shine 1s linear infinite;
}
@keyframes shine {
  from {left: -75px;}
  to {left: 150px;}
}
```

```html
<a href="">Button</a>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Такого результата Вы хотели добиться?

```css
@-webkit-keyframes sheen {
  to {
    -webkit-transform: skewY(-15deg) translateX(13.5em);
            transform: skewY(-15deg) translateX(13.5em);
  }
}
@keyframes sheen {
  to {
    -webkit-transform: skewY(-15deg) translateX(13.5em);
            transform: skewY(-15deg) translateX(13.5em);
  }
}
.wrapper {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
          transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.button {
  padding: 0.75em 2em;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #2194e0;
  border: 2px solid #2194e0;
  font-size: 24px;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 0.3em;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.button:before {
  content: "";
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  height: 500%;
  width: 1em;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: -1.5em;
  left: -4.5em;
  -webkit-transform: skewX(-25deg) translateX(0);
          transform: skewX(-25deg) translateX(0);
  transition: none;
}
.button:hover {
  background-color: #2194e0;
  color: #fff;
  border-bottom: 4px solid #1977b5;
}
.button:hover:before {
  animation: sheen 1s infinite ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <a href="#" class="button">Shiney!</a>
</div>
```

Comment: не совсем, но почти, у вас также как и у меня анимация начинает работать только после наведения на кнопку мышкой. А мне я хочу, и пытаюсь сделать чтоб она работал постоянно, с момента загрузки страницы.

Но все равно спасибо! Нашел вот такой вариант. Мне какраз подошел!  https://codepen.io/html5book/pen/QqZVPx